# Number index in parameters.yml corrupted Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I have in my parameters.yml an array of months which make the relation between the php function date('m') (months number with leading zero) and a letter choosen by default for generating a code.

```
months:
    01: 'A'
    02: 'B'
    03: 'C'
    04: 'D'
    05: 'E'
    06: 'F'
    07: 'G'
    08: 'H'
    09: 'I'
    10: 'J'
    11: 'K'
    12: 'L'
```

And here is the result of a var_dump($this->getParameters('months')) :

array (size=11)
  1 => string 'A' (length=1)
  2 => string 'B' (length=1)
  3 => string 'C' (length=1)
  4 => string 'D' (length=1)
  5 => string 'E' (length=1)
  6 => string 'F' (length=1)
  7 => string 'G' (length=1)
  0 => string 'H' (length=1)
  10 => string 'J' (length=1)
  11 => string 'K' (length=1)
  12 => string 'L' (length=1)

I finally resolve it removing the leading zero of the index, but is anybody know why the 08 is changed to 0 and 09 index disappear ?

Comment: Try to use strings for indexes like "01": "A", etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that if you don't use the quotes `01`, `02` ... `07` are interpreted as base 8 numbers (octal), `08` and `09` are `Invalid numeric literal` (invalid base 8 number), `10..12` are interpreted as integer numbers, you need use the quotes to fix this:

```
months:
    '01': 'A'
    '02': 'B'
    '03': 'C'
    '04': 'D'
    '05': 'E'
    '06': 'F'
    '07': 'G'
    '08': 'H'
    '09': 'I'
    '10': 'J'
    '11': 'K'
    '12': 'L'
```

See reference here http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html#numbers

Answer (score 1):

PHP uses the 0 prefix to denote that the number that follows is in octal. Thus 8 and 9 are invalid.

Just run `echo 08;` or `echo 09;` to see the error output.